# How to Validate Drop down menu options while submit

Tags: javascript, html, magento, drop-down-menu, checkout

I have added a "how did u reach us" drop down in my onepage checkout.

When I press the Place Order without select any option in the Drop Down I must get the error message "There is a required field".

But now the REQUIRED options are not working as required.

Customers can place order even if there is no selection in the drop down.

I think, When pressing Place Order button it's not checking for the required fields or it's considering the blank options as a value.

This is the code.

```
<?php
$survey_question_Status = Mage::getStoreConfig('grizzly_ordersocial/social/enable_social',Mage::app()->getStore());

$survey_question = Mage::getStoreConfig('grizzly_ordersocial/social/survey_question',Mage::app()->getStore());
?>
<form action="" class="where-did-you-hear" id="checkout-agreements" onsubmit="return false;">
    <?php if($survey_question_Status && isset($survey_question_Status)) { ?>
    <div class="buttons-set">
    <ul class="form-list">
        <li>
        <fieldset>
            <ul>
            <li>
                <label class="commentlabel required-entry" for="ordercomment-comment">
                <?php echo $survey_question; ?> <em>*</em></label>
                <div class="input-box required-entry">
<select class="validate-select" id="socialtype" name="socialtype" title="<?php echo $survey_question ?>">
<option value=""><?php echo $this->__("- Select -");?></option>
<option value="Friend/Relative/Acquaintance"><?php echo $this->__("Friend/Relative/Acquaintance");?></option>
<option value="Google search"><?php echo $this->__("Google search");?></option>
<option value="Gumtree Advert"><?php echo $this->__("Gumtree Advert");?></option>
<option value="Facebook"><?php echo $this->__("Facebook");?></option>
<option value="Other"><?php echo $this->__("Other");?></option>
</select>


                </div>
            </li>

            </ul>
        </fieldset>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

I think the Place Order button rules is making the issue.

Plz have a look at the onepage/review/button.phtml

```
<p class="required"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
<button type="submit" title="<?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?>" class="button btn-checkout" onclick="review.save();"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Place Order') ?></span></span></button>
```

Comment: What *exactly* is your question?

Comment: You are missing the require attribute on your select tag in the provided code. Also, when the question is only about your dropdown code, please only provide the code useful for your question, not all your code.

Comment: how to add the require attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `value=""` attribute from the first `<option>` element

Comment: it's not helping... ;)

Comment: You could possibly use <optgroup label="- Select -"></optgroup> instead, that might work.

Comment: when I press submit button that's not even considering the required options... the dropdown remains dummy... so frustrated...

Answer (score 0):

add this script at the end of page and pass form id `checkout-agreements` and field you want to required add `class="required-entry"`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //< ![CDATA[
        var customForm = new VarienForm('checkout-agreements');
    //]]>
</script>
```